# Error when resizing image stored in database

Tags: android, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I'm working on an Android App that has to communicate with a server to store/retrieve models in a database.
The application gives to the server an image encoded in base64, and the server stores it as a BlobProperty. 
When the application wants to retrieve the model, I would like to resize the image before the server could respond with it to the app.
In order to do so, I did something like:

```
image_to_resize = images.Image(model.image)
image_to_resize.resize(width=90, height=90)
image_to_resize.im_feeling_lucky()

thumbnail = image_to_resize.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
```

But when I try to retrieve the image, I get a NotImageError.

Any hint on why I get it?

Comment: You need to show the code updating `model.image` (and maybe its ndb Model as well).

Comment: have you converted the image back into binary from base64 before attempting to manipulate it as an image?

Comment: No, I have actually forgot to do that. It works now, thanks for pointing this out